# load routes after getting roles from an api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I created a react app, I added role based mechanism, the idea is that after the athentication, directly I send a request to an api to get the roles of the user, because the token contains only the username and I can not add any information on the payload.

so while getting thr roles from the api, I added a loder component that will block the user from using the app until the roles are loaded, at this point everything is working well, but when I reloaded the page, the app redirect me to the default route everytime, because the routes are not created yet, I would like to know how to block the app until the routes also are loaded? :

**App.tsx** :

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  const useRoles = useRoleBased(); // hook to get roles

  return (
    <>
      {useRoles?.loading(
        <Loader open backgroundColor="#ffffff" circleColor="primary" />
      )}
      <Box className={`mainSideBar ${openSideBar && 'openSideBar'}`}>
          <Router />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Router.tsx** :

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/logout', element: <ConfirmLogout /> },
  {
    path: '/dashboard-page',
    element: <DashboardPage />,
    allowedRoles: [Roles.Director, Roles.RequestFullAccess],
  },
  {
    path: '/profil',
    element: <RequestPage />,
    allowedRoles: [Roles.Manager],
  },
 
];

const Router: React.FC = () => {
  return <RolesAuthRoute routes={routes}></RolesAuthRoute>;
};

export default Router;
```

**RolesAuthRoute.tsx** :

```
export function RolesAuthRoute({ routes }: { routes: IRoutes[] }) {
  const userRoles = useSelector((state: any) => state?.roles?.roles);

  const isAllowed = (
  allowedRoles: Roles[] | undefined,
  userRoles: string[]) =>
      process.env.REACT_APP_ACTIVATE_ROLE_BASED_AUTH === 'false' ||
      !allowedRoles ||
      allowedRoles?.some((allowedRole) => userRoles?.includes(allowedRole)
  );

  return (
    <Routes>
      {routes.map((route) => {
        if (isAllowed(route?.allowedRoles, userRoles))
          return (
            <Route
              path={route?.path}
              element={route?.element}
              key={route?.path}
            />
          );
        else return null;
      })}
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} /> //this route is created in all cases
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return early (conditional rendering) to stop the router from rendering prematurely. You'll need to modify the hook to return the loading state as boolean instead of rendering the component as it seems to be currently implemented.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  const useRoles = useRoleBased(); // hook to get roles

  if(useRoles.isLoading){
    return <Loader open backgroundColor="#ffffff" circleColor="primary" />
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Box className={`mainSideBar ${openSideBar && 'openSideBar'}`}>
          <Router />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```